# The project was not built due to "Could not delete 'Coding Library/bin/assets'.".

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I have recently run into some problems ever since I updated Java for Minecraft Modding. If you'd like to see the full story, look at my other question. I have been modding minecraft and it has gone fine, yet when I updated to 64 bit java so that Feed the Beast would run faster, I have had some errors. I ended up in a spot where I couldn't find any of my projects, so I asked my first question. Someone reccomended Importing them, but when I imported the folder into Java and tried to run it, it told me that the files could not be imported or something (since my directory was the same as my workspace), I then made my workspace a random folder on my desktop, and imported. All the files were there, (Although I didn't see something there before called MDK Example. I tried to run it (it worked before), I receive an error which is the name of this post. If anyone can help me find how to fix this error, run my mod, and continue working it like I have been, please do!

Thanks :)

Comment: You should be able to import the folder even if it is in the same directory. I would suggest you better explain your question with some screenshots and with a clear cut problem statement instead of narrating it as a story.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the contents of "Coding Library/bin" from the system explorer, then return to eclipse and refresh your project, clean and build.